# How can be the database tier optimally designed to exploit both normalized as well as multidimensional data models?

Tags: normalization, olap, olap-cube

Our company's software is keeping transactional and report tables seperately. For optimization, the report schema has been de-normalized and table joins are minimized.

Can we optimally design database to exploit both normalized as well as multi-dimensional data models for OLAP? If yes, then how?